# Unity - web request only works on localhost

Tags: c#, http, sockets, unity-game-engine

I use Unity webRequest to fetch mjpeg stream from server. But it only works on localhost. If I move the server to another machine in the same LAN. Unity response connection refused.

The script is below. If the url is `http://locahost:7777/img` it's fine. I've also try `http://127.0.0.1:7777/img` and `http://192.168.0.2:7777/img` (localhost IP) all of them work fine. But when I host the server on another machine `http://192.168.0.7:7777/img` it fail.

```cs
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.4:7777/img");
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    List<byte> frameBuffer = new List<byte>();

    int lastByte = 0x00;
    bool addToBuffer = false;

    BufferedStream buffer = null;
    try
    {
      Stream stream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
      buffer = new BufferedStream(stream);
      trackedBuffers.Add(buffer);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
      Debug.LogError(ex);
    }
```

I've use HTML to test and all of them works great.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img src="http://localhost:7777/img">
  <img src="http://192.168.0.2:7777/img">
  <img src="http://192.168.0.4:7777/img">
  </img>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"it fail"* - is not a useful error description. Please provide the exact error you get in full detail.

Comment: Sounds like firewalls .

Comment: The error says "Connection refused"

I've test on browser using HTML and also use curl command for HTTP get request. Both of them works. Does Unity some how block incoming socket request?

Comment: Unity blocking incoming? Youre using unity as a webserver?

Comment: No, I use unity as a client. I mean "block" like browser blocks CORS request, something like that.

Comment: What do you see in the browser console?

Comment: The motion jpeg live streaming frames.

Comment: Having the same issue. By printing the web request's uri after I've created it, I noticed something important. When I pass in the uri in the formate "<ipaddress>:<port>/<path>" the uri it creates is "http://localhost:<ipaddress>:<port>/<path>". It's adding localhost to my uri if it's not already there...

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue but my initial conditions are somewhat different and the difference may be relevant. According to the [Unity Scripting API for WebRequest uri](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-url.html), assumptions are made about the given path based on how it starts. In my case, I was only passing in "<ipAddress>:<port><path>" whereas you're passing in "http://<ipAddress>:<port><path>". In my case, I found out it was prepending "http://localhost:" to my path which was incorrect. I fixed the issue simply be prepending my own path with "//" which, according to the documentation, causes Unity to prepend only the "http:" part. I don't know what it does for sure if you already prepended "http://".

TL;DR
Using the path format "//<ipAddress>:<port><path>" fixed the same issue for me.